# Bracha on french toast

Tags: halacha, blessing

Using leftover challah for French toast. I thought that because it's not in the original form (the main addition being eggs which also change the bread's appearance), mezonot is the proper bracha. But because it still contains majority of grains and is recognizable as a grain meal, it does not receive shehakol.

Still learning halachot of brachot rishonah, so I appreciate any corrections.

Comment: http://revach.net/article.php?id=2733 http://www.berachot.org/foods/letter_f.htm https://www.ou.org/torah/halacha/halacha-lmaaseh/food-fore-blessings-bracha-rishona-special-cases/

Comment: [OU says hamotzi](https://oukosher.org/guide-to-blessings/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We need two prior definitions.

1. The first, what is French Toast (["Pain
   perdu" in original French Language](http://www.marmiton.org/recettes/recette_pain-perdu_10975.aspx)),
2. and the second, what is considered as bread, and more precisely up
   to what degree of transformation the bread continues to be regarded
   as the bread according to Halacha.

We begin by finding the response of elements to the second issue in the Gemara.
The first quote is of the treaty Berachoth 37A

> והתניא הכוסס את החטה מברך עליה בורא פרי האדמה טחנה אפאה (פת {לגירסת התוספות})ובשלה בזמן שהפרוסות קיימות בתחלה מברך עליה המוציא לחם מן הארץ ולבסוף מברך עליה ג' ברכות אם אין הפרוסות קיימות בתחלה מברך עליה בורא מיני מזונות ולבסוף מברך עליה ברכה אחת מעין ג'
>   (It says that if making bread and then it is cooked in water, until the bread slices retain their integrity (Rashi says that they have not melted with cooking), we do "Hamotsi" and "3 Berachoth i.e. Bircath Hamazon").

We have to read a second passage on the back of the same sheet. It is a bit too long to be quoted in full here. We must especially remember that two actions have significance
cut pieces smaller than an 'olive' (Kezayith), and agglomerating small pieces. We limit our raisonement to the case of bread that has not been previously designed for for further processing (as French Toast is).
This is what Rashi learns from this second text:

> אמר רב ששת האי חביצא אף על גב דלית ביה פרורין כזית מברך עליו המוציא לחם מן הארץ אמר רבא והוא דאיכא עליה תוריתא דנהמא
>   (Rav Shesheth says that "this Chavitsa" despite that the crumbs are small than an olive, one blesses "Hamotsi". Rava said this is limited to cases in which the shape of the bread is preserved)

1. if a loaf is completely cut into smaller pieces than an olive an the pieces don't have the 'form of bread' (תוריתא דנהמא), the bracha is "mezonoth".
2. If the form of bread persist, the bracha is Hamotsi.
3. but if it persists one piece larger than an olive, we shall on small pieces 'Moti'. BHM and even if we eat a sufficient speed. (Tosfot explain that if it persists large slices, it is a sign that there was no **qualitative** *degradation*).
4. If all the loaf is crumbled, and then kneaded crumbs and this results in a new conglomerate,and then backed a second time, this is once again considered as whole bread.

---

Let's see how define the qualitative degradation of bread. Following Tosfoth If we let soak the bread in water for a long time until the water takes a whitish color, it is a sign that the bread is degraded. --> mezonoth --> Meeyn shalosh.
Rambam, Hilchoth Berachoth (3, 8):

> הפת שפתת אותה פיתים, **ובישלה בקדירה או לשה במרק**--***אם יש בפתיתין כזית***, או שניכר שהן פת ולא נשתנת צורתה--מברך עליה בתחילה, **המוציא**; ואם אין בהן כזית, או שעברה צורת הפת בבישול--מברך עליו בתחילה, בורא מיני מזונות.

In Kessef Mishne he conclude that as the same level of intermediate degradation, slices of less than Kezayith differ from the greater. The small are considered as no more bread and the great remain bread. (size is one of the common 'hallmarks' of bread). He differ at first glance from tosfoth because tosfoth descript only one sign of degradation that are as one of his consequence that big slices disintegrate.

***SA and Mishna Brura OC 168***, 10 follows this last advice (an interpretation in the Rambam)

---

**French Toast are big slices greater than kezayith. At first glance we recognize that these are slices of bread. So:
 1. Hamotsi;
 2. Birkath Hamazon.**
 3. I hope to explain later why little slice may also be Hamotsi. Lets write this as a question.

In French Toast, the slices are very briefly drenched in milk, then lightly fried in the pan. The little passage in milk don't alter the broad. The fact of even fry in plenty of oil is a known practice in the 'menahoth' is not obviously against the being bread (תוספות דף ל"ח ד"ה לחם העשוי לכותח). More, in Rama (188, 14 Rama), we consider that the small amount of oil is not used as an oil immersion.
**So toast fashioned into small slices short of a Kazayt ar perhaps hamotzi (להלכה ולא למעשה)**

If somewhat is erroneous I will appreciate corrections.

Answer (score 1):

It remains hamotzi so long as the bread was originally hamotzi and remains the size of a kzayis when made into french toast. It takes more drastic measures, such as cutting small or boiling, for bread that is hamotzi to lose this bracha.

Comment: It has absolutely Turitha denahama, the form of bread. Are you sure that if it is little thas kzayis when it initially was, it lose the Motsi in a case of prior normal bread?

Comment: @kouty It *may* lose the status. It may also not. But it must be smaller than a kzayit to start calculating that.

Comment: Editing your answer to include citations for its claims would improve its value for those of us who don't know you.

Comment: I heard similar from a rav at one point. If it's bread dipped in egg and cooked it's motzi, but if it's processed to be a new form of stuff called French toast then mezonot